# SQL insert multiple select in one query

Tags: mysql

I have a code for adding/updating records in the database. This works for a single entry.

```
insert into skills_to_user (id, user_id, skill_id, value)
select stu0.id, 4983, 3, 50 from skills_to_user stu0 where stu0.user_id = 4983 and stu0.skill_id = 3
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

What do I want to get?

```
insert into skills_to_user (id, user_id, skill_id, value)
values (8, 4983, 3, 50),
       (9, 4983, 4, 40),
       (10, 4983, 5, 30)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

When I try to use multiple select I get an error.

```
insert into skills_to_user (id, user_id, skill_id, value)
values (select id from skills_to_user where user_id = 4983 and skill_id = 3, 4983, 3, 50),
       (select id from skills_to_user where user_id = 4983 and skill_id = 4, 4983, 4, 40),
       (select id from skills_to_user where user_id = 4983 and skill_id = 5, 4983, 5, 30)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

That didn't work either

```
insert into skills_to_user (id, user_id, skill_id, value)
    select stu0.id, 4983, 3, 50 from skills_to_user stu0 where stu0.user_id = 4983 and stu0.skill_id = 3,
    select stu1.id, 4983, 4, 40 from skills_to_user stu1 where stu1.user_id = 4983 and stu1.skill_id = 4,
    select stu2.id, 4983, 5, 30 from skills_to_user stu2 where stu2.user_id = 4983 and stu2.skill_id = 5
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

Initially, the table looks like this [photo before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J27zV.png)

After the update, I expect the first record to update and 2 new records will be added. [photo after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG2Ap.png)

**P.S. The id is initially unknown, I can't use the exact id value. Therefore, I need to do a select and if there is such an id, I update the entry in the database, and if there is none, I create it.**

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table skills_to_user
(
    id           int auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_id      int                                not null,
    skill_id     int                                not null,
    value        int                                null,
    date_add     datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null,
    date_updated datetime                           null,
    constraint skills_to_user_id_uindex
        unique (id)
);
```

Comment: Probably the last one - BUT using a union instead of a list of select statements.

Comment: I tried using the join or union operator, but it didn't give results.

Comment: union and join are different things.

Comment: Please show an example

Comment: I would expect there to be a compound unique key on user_id and skill id - is there one? It would improve the question if you posted the table schema.

Comment: I added the code to create the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not seeing the problem here
given

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

create table t
(id int auto_increment primary key,
user_id int, skill_id int, value int);

alter table t add unique key uk1(user_id,skill_id);

insert into t(user_id, skill_id, value)
values (4983, 3, 50),
       (4983, 3, 40),
       (4983, 4, 60),
       (4983, 5, 30)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);

select * from t;

+----+---------+----------+-------+
| id | user_id | skill_id | value |
+----+---------+----------+-------+
|  1 |    4983 |        3 |    40 |
|  2 |    4983 |        4 |    60 |
|  3 |    4983 |        5 |    30 |
+----+---------+----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Edit - update date

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

create table t
(id int auto_increment primary key,
user_id int, skill_id int, value int,updated_date datetime on update current_timestamp);

alter table t add unique key uk1(user_id,skill_id);

insert into t(user_id, skill_id, value)
values (4983, 3, 50),
       (4983, 3, 40),
       (4983, 4, 60),
       (4983, 5, 30)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);

select * from t;

+----+---------+----------+-------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | skill_id | value | updated_date        |
+----+---------+----------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |    4983 |        3 |    40 | 2021-12-20 16:07:54 |
|  2 |    4983 |        4 |    60 | NULL                |
|  3 |    4983 |        5 |    30 | NULL                |
+----+---------+----------+-------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: the user ID cannot be unique, since there are many different users in the database. skills_id also cannot be unique, since different users may have the same skill
If you try to add a unique key to the data table, you will get an error.

Comment: Your understanding of a unique compound key is incorrect as in the example posted a user can have many skills and does not get an error.

Comment: I understand what you're talking about. This really works when creating a composite key. I am very grateful to you for your help!

Comment: Tell me, can I somehow update date_update, only if the record exists?

Comment: Is row 1 and 2 in my sample an example of that? If not I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I meant something like that or a trigger. 
alter table skills_to_user add date_update datetime on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default null null;

Comment: date_updated datetime  DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP insert on duplicate is an update where necessary see edit

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work that way for me(

Comment: Publish an example of your issue in a fiddle and I will have a look.

Comment: If the value does not change, then the record is not updated.
For example, there is a recording fact. But in the table now value = 0. And I'm trying to update 0 to 0. But I still need to update the date_update field because the fact of the record was.

Comment: You want to log a change date even when nothing has changed? That's not possible using inbuilt functionality. You would have to approach this a different way for example in a procedure where you check if nothing will change and update or if something will change then let the ON UPDATE handle it..

Answer (score 0):

You want to read records from one table and insert into same table?
I think, you will get a DB lock or so.

try

```
insert into skills_to_user (id, user_id, skill_id, value)
select stu0.id, 4983, 3, 50 from skills_to_user
```

Comment: This only works for 1 record

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're asking, but if you want to add multiple inputs on the same query is something like.

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6','test7','test8'),('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6','test7','test8')
```